# Не получается создать список на Racket (scheme)

Tags: list, scheme, racket

У меня есть задача: дан список (X1...Xn) с различными элементами и число k. Найти k-тый элемент по величине.
Довольно долго гуглю информацию, но наглядных и понятных решений вообще по поиску элементов в списке на языках данного типа найти не получается. Есть догадки, что можно как-то с помощью рекурсии, используя cdr и car сделать, но пока ничего работающего не вышло. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Посмотрите на алгоритм quickeselect. Вероятно, на этой вашей racket его можно реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

просто вывести элемент из списка по его индексу можно с помощью функции [`(list-ref lst pos)`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._list-ref%29%29). пример (элементы нумеруются начиная с нуля):

```
> (list-ref '(5 7 3 6) 0)
5
```

а отсортировать список можно с помощью функции [`(sort lst less-than?)`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._sort%29%29):

```
> (sort '(5 7 3 6) <)
(3 5 6 7)
```

и обе функции вместе:

```
> (list-ref (sort '(5 7 3 6) <) 0)
3
```

---

p.s. примеры проверялись в `guile`, но затрагивают они настолько базовые понятия, что должны работать идентично и в любой другой реализации языка scheme.